# Gmaps4rails make marker draggable and get its coordinates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

Is it possible to make a marker draggable and to get its coordinates in gmaps4rails, that the user could drag marker to choose the point he wants and get his chosen point coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

It's not implemented in the gem.

But don't forget that you have access to all objects created. Example, the map could be retrieved with: `Gmaps4Rails.map`

You could take inspiration from: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Javascript-goodies